# 8-Puzzle Solution executes infinitely

Tags: java, computer-science, artificial-intelligence

I am looking for a solution to [8-puzzle](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall12/cos226/assignments/8puzzle.html) problem using the `A* Algorithm`. I found [**this**](http://code.google.com/p/a-star-eight-puzzle/source/browse/trunk/+a-star-eight-puzzle/420proj1/src/?r=10) project on the internet.  Please see the files - `proj1` and `EightPuzzle`. The proj1 contains the entry point for the program(the `main()` function) and EightPuzzle describes a particular state of the puzzle. Each state is an object of the 8-puzzle. 
I feel that there is nothing wrong in the logic.  But it loops forever for these two inputs that I have tried : `{8,2,7,5,1,6,3,0,4}` and `{3,1,6,8,4,5,7,2,0}`. Both of them are valid input states. What is wrong with the code?

---

**Note**

- For better viewing copy the code in a Notepad++ or some other text
  editor(which has the capability to recognize java source file)
  because there are lot of comments in the code.
- Since A* requires a heuristic, they have provided the option of using
  manhattan distance and a heuristic that calculates the number of
  misplaced tiles. And to ensure that the best heuristic is executed
  first, they have implemented a `PriorityQueue`. The `compareTo()`
  function is implemented in the `EightPuzzle` class.
- The input to the program can be changed by changing the value of `p1d` in the `main()` function of `proj1` class.
- The reason I am telling that there exists solution for the two my above inputs is because the applet [here](http://www.brian-borowski.com/Software/Puzzle/) solves them. Please ensure that you select 8-puzzle from the options in the applet.

  **EDIT1**
  I gave this input `{0,5,7,6,8,1,2,4,3}`. It took about `10 seconds` and gave a result with **26 moves**. But the applet gave a result with `24 moves` in `0.0001 seconds` with `A*`.

  **EDIT2**
  While debugging I noticed that as nodes are expanded, the new nodes, after sometime, all have a heuristic - `f_n` as `11` or `12`. They never seem to decrease. So after sometime all the states in the `PriorityQueue(openset)` have a heuristic of 11 or 12. So there is not much to choose from, to which node to expand. As the least is 11 and the highest is 12. Is this normal?
  **EDIT3**
  This is the snippet(in **proj1-astar()**) where the infinite looping happening. **openset** is the PriorityQueue containing unexpanded nodes and **closedset** is the LinkedList containing expanded nodes.

while(openset.size() > 0){

```
                    EightPuzzle x = openset.peek();


                    if(x.mapEquals(goal))
                    {

                             Stack<EightPuzzle> toDisplay = reconstruct(x);
                             System.out.println("Printing solution... ");
                             System.out.println(start.toString());
                             print(toDisplay);
                             return;
                             
                    }          
                    closedset.add(openset.poll());
                    LinkedList <EightPuzzle> neighbor = x.getChildren();              
                    while(neighbor.size() > 0)
                    {
                            EightPuzzle y = neighbor.removeFirst();
                            if(closedset.contains(y)){
                                    continue;
                            }          
                            if(!closedset.contains(y)){
                                    openset.add(y);
                            }              
                    }
               
            }
```

---

**EDIT4**
**I have got the cause of this infinite loop**. See my answer. But it takes about **25-30 seconds** to execute, which is quite a long time. A* should do much faster than this. the applet does this in **0.003 seconds**. **I will award the bounty for improving the performance.**

---

**For** quick reference I have pasted the the two classes without the comments :

### EightPuzzle

```
 import java.util.*;
    
    public class EightPuzzle implements Comparable <Object> {
           
           
            int[] puzzle = new int[9];
            int h_n= 0;
            int hueristic_type = 0;
            int g_n = 0;
            int f_n = 0;
            EightPuzzle parent = null;
    
           
            public EightPuzzle(int[] p, int h_type, int cost)
            {
                    this.puzzle = p;
                    this.hueristic_type = h_type;
                    this.h_n = (h_type == 1) ?  h1(p) : h2(p);
                    this.g_n = cost;
                    this.f_n = h_n + g_n;
            }
            public int getF_n()
            {
                    return f_n;
            }
            public void setParent(EightPuzzle input)
            {
                    this.parent = input;
            }
            public EightPuzzle getParent()
            {
                    return this.parent;
            }
    
            public int inversions()
            {
                    /*
                     * Definition: For any other configuration besides the goal,
                     * whenever a tile with a greater number on it precedes a
                     * tile with a smaller number, the two tiles are said to be inverted
                     */
                    int inversion = 0;
                    for(int i = 0; i < this.puzzle.length; i++ )
                    {
                            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                            {
                                    if(this.puzzle[i] != 0 && this.puzzle[j] != 0)
                                    {
                                    if(this.puzzle[i] < this.puzzle[j])
                                            inversion++;
                                    }
                            }
    
                    }
                    return inversion;
                   
            }
            public int h1(int[] list)
            // h1 = the number of misplaced tiles
            {
                    int gn = 0;
                    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
                    {
                            if(list[i] != i && list[i] != 0)
                                    gn++;
                    }
                    return gn;
            }
            public LinkedList<EightPuzzle> getChildren()
            {
                    LinkedList<EightPuzzle> children = new LinkedList<EightPuzzle>();
                    int loc = 0;
            int temparray[] = new int[this.puzzle.length];
            EightPuzzle rightP, upP, downP, leftP;
                    while(this.puzzle[loc] != 0)
                    {
                            loc++;
                    }
                    if(loc % 3 == 0){
                            temparray = this.puzzle.clone();
                            temparray[loc] = temparray[loc + 1];
                            temparray[loc + 1] = 0;
                            rightP = new EightPuzzle(temparray, this.hueristic_type, this.g_n + 1);
                            rightP.setParent(this);
                            children.add(rightP);
    
                    }else if(loc % 3 == 1){
                    //add one child swaps with right
                            temparray = this.puzzle.clone();
                            temparray[loc] = temparray[loc + 1];
                            temparray[loc + 1] = 0;
                           
                            rightP = new EightPuzzle(temparray, this.hueristic_type, this.g_n + 1);
                            rightP.setParent(this);
                            children.add(rightP);
                            //add one child swaps with left
                            temparray = this.puzzle.clone();
                            temparray[loc] = temparray[loc - 1];
                            temparray[loc - 1] = 0;
                           
                            leftP = new EightPuzzle(temparray, this.hueristic_type, this.g_n + 1);
                            leftP.setParent(this);
                            children.add(leftP);
                    }else if(loc % 3 == 2){
                    // add one child swaps with left
                            temparray = this.puzzle.clone();
                            temparray[loc] = temparray[loc - 1];
                            temparray[loc - 1] = 0;
                           
                            leftP = new EightPuzzle(temparray, this.hueristic_type, this.g_n + 1);
                            leftP.setParent(this);
                            children.add(leftP);
                    }              
                   
                    if(loc / 3 == 0){
                    //add one child swaps with lower
                            temparray = this.puzzle.clone();
                            temparray[loc] = temparray[loc + 3];
                            temparray[loc + 3] = 0;
                           
                            downP = new EightPuzzle(temparray, this.hueristic_type, this.g_n + 1);
    
                            downP.setParent(this);
    
                            children.add(downP);
                   
                           
                    }else if(loc / 3 == 1 ){
                            //add one child, swap with upper
                            temparray = this.puzzle.clone();
                            temparray[loc] = temparray[loc - 3];
                            temparray[loc - 3] = 0;
                           
                            upP = new EightPuzzle(temparray, this.hueristic_type, this.g_n + 1);
                            upP.setParent(this);
    
                            children.add(upP);
                            //add one child, swap with lower
                            temparray = this.puzzle.clone();
                            temparray[loc] = temparray[loc + 3];
                            temparray[loc + 3] = 0;
                           
                            downP = new EightPuzzle(temparray, this.hueristic_type, this.g_n + 1);
                            downP.setParent(this);
    
                            children.add(downP);
                    }else if (loc / 3 == 2 ){
                            //add one child, swap with upper
                            temparray = this.puzzle.clone();
                            temparray[loc] = temparray[loc - 3];
                            temparray[loc - 3] = 0;
                           
                            upP = new EightPuzzle(temparray, this.hueristic_type, this.g_n + 1);
                            upP.setParent(this);
    
                            children.add(upP);
                    }
    
                    return children;
            }
            public int h2(int[] list)
            // h2 = the sum of the distances of the tiles from their goal positions
            // for each item find its goal position
            // calculate how many positions it needs to move to get into that position
            {
                    int gn = 0;
                    int row = 0;
                    int col = 0;
                    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
                    {
                            if(list[i] != 0)
                            {
                                    row = list[i] / 3;
                                    col = list[i] % 3;
                                    row = Math.abs(row - (i / 3));
                                    col = Math.abs(col - (i % 3));
                                    gn += row;
                                    gn += col;
                            }
                           
                    }
                    return gn;
            }
    
            public String toString()
            {
                    String x = "";
                    for(int i = 0; i < this.puzzle.length; i++){
                            x += puzzle[i] + " ";
                            if((i + 1) % 3 == 0)
                                    x += "\n";
                    }
                    return x;
            }
            public int compareTo(Object input) {
                   
                   
                    if (this.f_n < ((EightPuzzle) input).getF_n())
                            return -1;
                    else if (this.f_n > ((EightPuzzle) input).getF_n())
                            return 1;
                    return 0;
            }
           
            public boolean equals(EightPuzzle test){
                    if(this.f_n != test.getF_n())
                            return false;
                    for(int i = 0 ; i < this.puzzle.length; i++)
                    {
                            if(this.puzzle[i] != test.puzzle[i])
                                    return false;
                    }
                    return true;
            }
            public boolean mapEquals(EightPuzzle test){
                    for(int i = 0 ; i < this.puzzle.length; i++)
                    {
                            if(this.puzzle[i] != test.puzzle[i])
                                    return false;
                    }
                    return true;
            }
    
    }
```

### proj1

```
import java.util.*;

public class proj1 {

        /**
         * @param args
         */
       
        public static void main(String[] args) {
               
               
                int[] p1d = {1, 4, 2, 3, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8};
                int hueristic = 2;
                EightPuzzle start = new EightPuzzle(p1d, hueristic, 0);
                int[] win = { 0, 1, 2,
                                          3, 4, 5,
                                          6, 7, 8};
                EightPuzzle goal = new EightPuzzle(win, hueristic, 0);
               
                astar(start, goal);

               

        }
       
        public static void astar(EightPuzzle start, EightPuzzle goal)
        {
                if(start.inversions() % 2 == 1)
                {
                        System.out.println("Unsolvable");
                        return;
                }
//              function A*(start,goal)
//           closedset := the empty set                 // The set of nodes already evaluated.
                LinkedList<EightPuzzle> closedset = new LinkedList<EightPuzzle>();
//           openset := set containing the initial node // The set of tentative nodes to be evaluated. priority queue
                PriorityQueue<EightPuzzle> openset = new PriorityQueue<EightPuzzle>();

                openset.add(start);
               

                while(openset.size() > 0){
//               x := the node in openset having the lowest f_score[] value
                        EightPuzzle x = openset.peek();

//               if x = goal
                        if(x.mapEquals(goal))
                        {
//                   return reconstruct_path(came_from, came_from[goal])
                                 Stack<EightPuzzle> toDisplay = reconstruct(x);
                                 System.out.println("Printing solution... ");
                                 System.out.println(start.toString());
                                 print(toDisplay);
                                 return;
                                 
                        }
//               remove x from openset
//               add x to closedset
                        closedset.add(openset.poll());
                        LinkedList <EightPuzzle> neighbor = x.getChildren();
//               foreach y in neighbor_nodes(x)                
                        while(neighbor.size() > 0)
                        {
                                EightPuzzle y = neighbor.removeFirst();
//                   if y in closedset
                                if(closedset.contains(y)){
//                       continue
                                        continue;
                                }
//                   tentative_g_score := g_score[x] + dist_between(x,y)
//      
//                   if y not in openset
                                if(!closedset.contains(y)){
//                       add y to openset
                                        openset.add(y);
//                      
                                }
//                 
                        }
//               
                }
        }

        public static void print(Stack<EightPuzzle> x)
        {
                while(!x.isEmpty())
                {
                        EightPuzzle temp = x.pop();
                        System.out.println(temp.toString());
                }
        }

        public static Stack<EightPuzzle> reconstruct(EightPuzzle winner)
        {
                Stack<EightPuzzle> correctOutput = new Stack<EightPuzzle>();
               
                while(winner.getParent() != null)
                {
                correctOutput.add(winner);
                winner = winner.getParent();
                }

                return correctOutput;
        }
       
        }
```

Comment: I'm confused. You say that there is nothing wrong with the logic, but inputs fail. Are you trying to fix your code? Or do you want a critique of it?

Comment: @ThomasOwens : I want to know the reason why it is not working as expected. Where is it going wrong? I want a fix.

Comment: Are you sure your puzzle is sovlable?  Half aren't.

Comment: @Novak: OP notes that another application found a solution for those inputs.  You can quickly verify that both are even permutations.

Comment: And the Eclipse debugger wasn't of any use?

Comment: @ChrisGerken : I tried the eclipse debugger after you pointed out. During debugging, I checked the values of openset(priority queue) and closedset(linkedlist). The values are as they should be. There is a derease in the priority queue value by 1 each time but 2-4 neighbours are added. The comparator is also executing properly. Do you have any better way of debuggin? If so please tell. I will do it.

Comment: @downvoters : Why has the question been down voted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a proposal.  My timer reports 0 ms for your example. On the harder puzzle given here, which needs 31 moves to complete, it takes 96 ms.

A `HashSet` makes much more sense for the closed set than your linked list.  It has O(1) time insert and membership test, where your linked list requires time proportional to the length of the list, which is constantly growing.

You are using extra data structures and code that make your program more complex and slower than needed. Think more, code less, and study others' good code to overcome this. Mine is not perfect (no code ever is), but it's a place to start.

I used as the heuristic the max of Manhattan distances from each tile's currrent position to its goal. The choice of heuristic does not affect the number of steps in the solution, but it *will* affect run time enormously. For example, h=0 will produce brute force breadth first search.

Note that for A* to provide an optimal solution, the heuristic can never *over-estimate* the actual minimum number of steps to the goal. If it does so, the solution is finds might not be the shortest possible.  I'm not positive the "inversions" hueristic  has this property.

```
package eightpuzzle;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class EightPuzzle {

    // Tiles for successfully completed puzzle.
    static final byte [] goalTiles = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    // A* priority queue.
    final PriorityQueue <State> queue = new PriorityQueue<State>(100, new Comparator<State>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(State a, State b) { 
            return a.priority() - b.priority();
        }
    });

    // The closed state set.
    final HashSet <State> closed = new HashSet <State>();

    // State of the puzzle including its priority and chain to start state.
    class State {
        final byte [] tiles;    // Tiles left to right, top to bottom.
        final int spaceIndex;   // Index of space (zero) in tiles  
        final int g;            // Number of moves from start.
        final int h;            // Heuristic value (difference from goal)
        final State prev;       // Previous state in solution chain.

        // A* priority function (often called F in books).
        int priority() {
            return g + h;
        }

        // Build a start state.
        State(byte [] initial) {
            tiles = initial;
            spaceIndex = index(tiles, 0);
            g = 0;
            h = heuristic(tiles);
            prev = null;
        }

        // Build a successor to prev by sliding tile from given index.
        State(State prev, int slideFromIndex) {
            tiles = Arrays.copyOf(prev.tiles, prev.tiles.length);
            tiles[prev.spaceIndex] = tiles[slideFromIndex];
            tiles[slideFromIndex] = 0;
            spaceIndex = slideFromIndex;
            g = prev.g + 1;
            h = heuristic(tiles);
            this.prev = prev;
        }

        // Return true iif this is the goal state.
        boolean isGoal() {
            return Arrays.equals(tiles, goalTiles);
        }

        // Successor states due to south, north, west, and east moves.
        State moveS() { return spaceIndex > 2 ? new State(this, spaceIndex - 3) : null; }       
        State moveN() { return spaceIndex < 6 ? new State(this, spaceIndex + 3) : null; }       
        State moveE() { return spaceIndex % 3 > 0 ? new State(this, spaceIndex - 1) : null; }       
        State moveW() { return spaceIndex % 3 < 2 ? new State(this, spaceIndex + 1) : null; }

        // Print this state.
        void print() {
            System.out.println("p = " + priority() + " = g+h = " + g + "+" + h);
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i += 3)
                System.out.println(tiles[i] + " " + tiles[i+1] + " " + tiles[i+2]);
        }

        // Print the solution chain with start state first.
        void printAll() {
            if (prev != null) prev.printAll();
            System.out.println();
            print();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj instanceof State) {
                State other = (State)obj;
                return Arrays.equals(tiles, other.tiles);
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Arrays.hashCode(tiles);
        }
    }

    // Add a valid (non-null and not closed) successor to the A* queue.
    void addSuccessor(State successor) {
        if (successor != null && !closed.contains(successor)) 
            queue.add(successor);
    }

    // Run the solver.
    void solve(byte [] initial) {

        queue.clear();
        closed.clear();

        // Click the stopwatch.
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Add initial state to queue.
        queue.add(new State(initial));

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {

            // Get the lowest priority state.
            State state = queue.poll();

            // If it's the goal, we're done.
            if (state.isGoal()) {
                long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
                state.printAll();
                System.out.println("elapsed (ms) = " + elapsed);
                return;
            }

            // Make sure we don't revisit this state.
            closed.add(state);

            // Add successors to the queue.
            addSuccessor(state.moveS());
            addSuccessor(state.moveN());
            addSuccessor(state.moveW());
            addSuccessor(state.moveE());
        }
    }

    // Return the index of val in given byte array or -1 if none found.
    static int index(byte [] a, int val) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            if (a[i] == val) return i;
        return -1;
    }

    // Return the Manhatten distance between tiles with indices a and b.
    static int manhattanDistance(int a, int b) {
        return Math.abs(a / 3 - b / 3) + Math.abs(a % 3 - b % 3);
    }

    // For our A* heuristic, we just use max of Manhatten distances of all tiles.
    static int heuristic(byte [] tiles) {
        int h = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++)
            if (tiles[i] != 0)
                h = Math.max(h, manhattanDistance(i, tiles[i]));
        return h;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // This is a harder puzzle than the SO example
        byte [] initial = { 8, 0, 6, 5, 4, 7, 2, 3, 1 };

        // This is taken from the SO example.
        //byte [] initial = { 1, 4, 2, 3, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

        new EightPuzzle().solve(initial);
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I used hashmap for closedset and added a hashcode function in EightPuzzle. I missed the hashMap idea. Thanks:)

Comment: I meant to add that either the example `{0,5,7,6,8,1,2,4,3}` does not have a 24-move solution or both our codes are buggy. Even with brute force BFS I am getting 26 moves, just as you are. You should look at the reported 24 moves carefully. I think you'll find an error.

Comment: The goals state in the applet(which gave 26 moves) was 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0 but our goal state is 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. Sorry, I noticed it only now

Comment: By any chance, have you tried to solve the 15 puzzle using the above algorithm(A*)? Because I tried and it takes about minimum 5 seconds to solve. The applet has has used A* for 15 puzzle, only IDA. So is A* not suitable for 15 puzzle?

Comment: I have not tried 15, but if you post an example problem I can do that. As I said, performance of A* is all about the goodness of your heuristic. To speed up the solution, think harder about the heuristic. It's unlikely there is a better algorithm than A* for this kind of problem.

Comment: I have posted an "example problem" here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229722/need-a-practical-solution-for-creating-pattern-database5-5-5-for-15-puzzle

Answer (score 1):

Found out the problem. This is the condition that is used to check if a node is present in **closedset**

```
if(!closedset.contains(y))
```

A linkedlist(closedset) executes the **contains()** by calling the **equals()** of the class, in this case **EightPuzzle**. The equals function in **EightPuzzle** is defined as follows

```
public boolean equals(EightPuzzle test){

                if(this.f_n != ((EightPuzzle)test).getF_n())
                       return false;
            //System.out.println("in equals");
                for(int i = 0 ; i < this.puzzle.length; i++)
                {
                        if(this.puzzle[i] != ((EightPuzzle)test).puzzle[i])
                                return false;
                }
                return true;
        }
```

But this function was never called because if you want to override the **equals()** of **Object** class the correct signature should be

```
 public boolean equals(Object test).
```

**One more change required** - comment the first two lines of the equals()

I got the answer. But the code still takes **25-30** seconds for some inputs. This is not expected with A*. the applet solves the puzzle in **0.003 seconds**. If someone has an idea how to improve the performance, please do tell me.
 I will award the bounty to that person.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer for optimization from another forum. 
Change `openset.size()` and `neightbor.size()` 
to
 `openset.isEmpty()` and `neightbor.isEmpty()` respectively.
 `size()` iterates through the whole list and as the list gets bigger, it takes more and more time. And also change the  `EightPuzzle x = openset.peek();` 

to
  `EightPuzzle x = openset.poll();` and reuse x, instead of calling `peek()` and the `poll()`

Now it processes within `1 second`

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is nothing wrong with your code, however, note that not all 8-puzzle problems are solvable! so check first if "{8,2,7,5,1,6,3,0,4} and {3,1,6,8,4,5,7,2,0}" are solvable 8-puzzles.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Hello manetsus, I removed the link since it is not really answering the question