# Give a part of chessboard of 15-puzzle, how to get all of the state of the the part chessboard using BFS?

Tags: java, breadth-first-search, sliding-tile-puzzle

the board is like this:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

the '0' represents that is empty, we can move the non-zero number to the '0'.
so how to get all of the state of the board using BFS?

for example, there are two state of the board:

```
1 2 3 4
0 0 0 0
5 6 7 0
0 0 0 0

1 2 3 0
4 0 0 0
5 0 0 0
6 7 0 0
```

The reason I ask this question is that I need to process all of the 15-puzzle state using Disjoint pattern database to solve the nearly most difficult state of 15-puzzle in 1 minutes.

```
15 14 13 12
11 10 9 8
7 6 5 4
3 1 2 0
```

Comment: Do you know that there are 10461394944000 (=16!/2) possible states? Storing only 1 byte per state would mean about 10 TB.

Comment: @Henry, There are 7 points, is C(16, 7) * A(7, 7)

Comment: Right, I was calculating the full puzzle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to process all of the 15-puzzle state [..] to solve the nearly most difficult state of 15-puzzle in 1 minutes

### Approach 1 - using a database and storing all states

For reasons given by [Henry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1796579) as well, and also supported by [1], solving this problem using a database would require generating the entire [**A_15**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_group) , storing all of it and then finding the shortest path, or some path between a given state and the solved state. This would require a lot of space and a lot of time. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13419588/827519) for an outline of this approach.

### Approach 2 - using a specialized depth-first search algorithm

[Here is an implementation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155505) of this search strategy that uses the [IDA algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_A*).

### Approach 3 - using computational group theory

Yet another way to handle this in a much shorter amount of time is to use GAP (which implements a variant of [Schreier-Sims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schreier%E2%80%93Sims_algorithm)) in order to decompose a given word into a product of generators. There [is an example in the docs](https://www.gap-system.org/Doc/Examples/rubik.html) that shows how to use it to solve the Rubik's cube, and it can be adapted to the 15-puzzle too [2].

---

[1] [Permutation Puzzles - A Mathematical Perspective by Jamie Mulholland](https://www.sfu.ca/%7Ejtmulhol/math302/notes/permutation-puzzles-book.pdf) - see page 103 and 104 for solvability criteria, and the state space being `|A_15| ~ 653 billion`

[2] [link2](http://jultika.oulu.fi/files/nbnfioulu-201303141099.pdf) - page 37